# Multiple condition based click event in ionic 3 (Angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-directive

In my ionic application, I would like to have a conditional based click event,

```
        <div class='class1' *ngIf='cndtn != "undefined"' 
          (click)='cndtn1 && cndtn2 then functionToCall()'>
          <ion-icon class='icon-location'></ion-icon>{{xxxx}}
          <ion-icon class='icon-arrow-right floatRight iconArrowRight'></ion-icon>
        </div>
```

In the above code, `functionToCall`  should be executed only when `cndtn1 && cndtn2` satisfy, any idea how to implement

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call `functionToCall()` anyway and then check `cndtn1` and `cndtn2` there. Like:

```
functionToCall() {
   if (!cndtn1 || !cndtn2) {
       return;
   else {
   // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: there are many other functions where i need to put same condtions...so I wanted to manage it in html file rather than ts file.

can we do something like `(click)="cndtn1 && cndtn2 ? func() : xxx"` ???

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde Yes, I believe that's valid syntax.